# Whitespace error in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have a very confusing problem to deal with.

The following code runs fine when I directly paste it into the ghci console but does not run when loading it from a file.

```
all' :: (a->Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
all' cond list
    | filter cond list == list = True
    | otherwise = False
```

I get the following error message:

```
5-1.hs:11:28:
    No instance for (Eq a) arising from a use of `=='
    Possible fix:
      add (Eq a) to the context of
        the type signature for all' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
    In the expression: filter cond list == list
    In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                   an equation for all':
      filter cond list == list
    In an equation for all':
        all' cond list
          | filter cond list == list = True
          | otherwise = False
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're inputting it into GHCi one line at a time with multiple `let`s, something like

```
> let all' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
> let all' cond list = if filter cond list == list then True else False
```

This won't work since these two declarations are executed separately from each other, with the latter overriding the former.  What you can do is turn on multiline input in GHCi

```
> :set +m
> let all' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
|     all' cond list
|         | filter cond list == list = True
|         | otherwise = False
```

At which point you would encounter the same error.

The error you see is because you're using `==` to compare the result of the filter to the original list, which requires comparing each element of the filtered and original list.  In order to do that, the elements of that list must belong to a type that implements the `Eq` typeclass (think interface from OOP, it's similar).  However, in the type signature to your function you've specified that `a` doesn't belong to any type class, it can be any type.  To fix this, simply add `Eq a` to the *context* of the type signature

```
--            v  This is the context
> let all' :: Eq a => (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
>     all' cond list = ...
```

However, this is not the best way to implement `all`.  Firstly, the guards/if statement are unnecessary.  You're calculating a `Bool`, and if it's `True` you return `True`, if it's `False` you return `False`, which is just putting an extra computation in there that isn't needed, just return the `Bool` you calculate:

```
all' cond list = filter cond list == list
```

This still leaves the problem that you have to specify `Eq` in the context of the type signature.  Obviously, that isn't ideal since we'd want to be able to call `all'` on a list of functions, or whatever other type that might come along.  So how do we remove the `==` from the definition?  The easiest way would be to compare lengths instead of elements:

```
all' cond list = length (filter cond list) == length list
```

And while this would work and have the desired type, it still isn't the most efficient solution.  What if the first element in the list fails the `cond`?  Ideally we would exit the computation as soon as an element fails the condition.  Instead we can modify the definition of `all'` so that it is aware of individual elements in the list:

```
all' cond [] = True
```

First, state that `all' cond []` is always `True`, technically all elements of an empty list pass the `cond`, since there are no elements to fail it.  Next:

```
all' cond (x:xs)
    | cond x   = ...
    | otherwse = ...
```

This is the next case that we have to handle, and given `cond`, `x`, and `xs`, and there aren't many things we can do with them other than apply `cond` to `x`.  In the event that `cond x` is `False`, we want the function to exit early with `False`:

```
all' cond (x:xs)
    | cond x   = ...
    | otherwse = False
```

If `x` passes the `cond`, we want to keep checking the rest of the list:

```
all' cond (x:xs)
    | cond x   = all' cond xs
    | otherwse = False
```

And for the complete definition:

```
all' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
all' cond [] = True
all' cond (x:xs)
    | cond x   = all' cond xs
    | otherwse = False
```

We also could have written it as

```
all' cond [] = True
all' cond (x:xs) = cond x && all' cond xs
```

Since the `&&` operator will short circuit the computation as soon as it sees a `False`.

Contrast this the definition of `all` in `Prelude`:

```
and xs = foldr (&&) True xs
all cond xs = and $ map cond xs
```

(Note: The definitions in `Prelude` use the point-free versions of these functions).  This is much simpler but achieves the same thing.  The `foldr` function is simply used to generalize away this sort of recursion pattern.  It may be a little harder to see here, but `all'` is just a combination of applying `cond` to every element of the list then doing a logical AND on those results.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer. I really appreciate the work you put into it and learned a lot from it.
The thing that confused me most, was that:
<code>
    Prelude>let all' cond list = filter cond list == list
</code>
works flawless. Only when you want to load the above content via a file you need the
    Eq a =>

Comment: @xergon Examine the type of `all' cond list = filter cond list == list`, it will have `Eq a` in it.  GHC can correctly infer what the type of this function is, and since you use `==` on the list itself, it uses the instance `instance Eq a => Eq [a] where ...`  It's not when you're loading it from a file or not, it's when you're specifying an explicit type signature for your function.

Comment: All right, I got it now. Thank you so much for all your work :)

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `==` in

```
filter cond list == list = True
```

means that `a` must implement `Eq` i.e. your type signature should be:

```
all' :: Eq a => (a->Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, a perfect tl;dr from above :)